# Skip tests or classes in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I want to **Skip** (so I will see at the report that the tests / classes were skipped) with `ITestListener`, what I did is the listener class like so:

```
    @Override
public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    String deviceName = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("deviceName");
    System.out.println("device name : "+deviceName);
    String className = context.getClass().getSimpleName();
    System.out.println("class name : "+className);
    if(!deviceName.contains("Galaxy S8")) {
        System.out.println("Skipping class name : "+className);
        throw new SkipException("Skipping class: " + className);
    }
}
```

and I have test class :

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void installAndDenyPhoneAccess() {
    onePlus6ProInstallProcess.denyPhoneAccess();
}
```

at the `testng.xml` I added the listener:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite"  parallel = "tests" 
configfailurepolicy="continue">

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.qa.listeners.TestListener" />
</listeners>

<test name="Samsung Note 10 - 5G">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.qa.listeners.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
    <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
    <parameter name="udid" value="RPM" />
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="Note 10 - 5G" />
    <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
    <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
    <classes>
        <class name="note5.Installation"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Redmi 6A">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.qa.listeners.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
    <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
    <parameter name="udid" value="192b" />
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="Redmi 6A" />
    <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
    <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
    <classes>
        <class name="redmi6A.Installation"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="OnePlus 6 Pro">
    <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
    <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
    <parameter name="udid" value="73" />
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="onePlus 6Pro" />
    <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
    <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
    <classes>
        <class name="onePlus6Pro.Installation"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Galaxy S8">
    <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
    <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
    <parameter name="udid" value="ce3cb10c" />
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="Galaxy S8" />
    <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
    <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
    <classes>
        <class name="galaxyS8.Installation"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Samsung A21s">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.qa.listeners.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
    <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
    <parameter name="udid" value="RdM" />
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="Samsung A21s" />
    <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
    <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
    <classes>
        <class name="a21S.Installation"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

now the tests are not skipped and anyhow not all of them when runing together, only when run two.
So how to skip it? and also how to skip the all class if it can?

Comment: All the code looks correct. Can you also print `System.out.println(testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getName())` ?

Comment: Yes, I printed it, it's in the code

Comment: I can confirm that if your class contains `a12S` in the name and `annotation.setEnabled(false)` invoked the method from this class will not be executed. I've tested this behavior with testNG 7.5 on a simple example.

Comment: If something doesn't work, the issue might be: 1) your test-class name doesn't contain `a12S`. 2) you are using some testNG version, which has a bug (it's unlikely) 3) you've applied multiple `IAnnotationTransformer` listeners. One disables the test, but the other enables. 4) listener applied in the code on class, not in xml (but you sayed that it's in xml) 5) junit @Test annotation instead of testng. I've mentioned all the potential reasouns I might remember.

Comment: first of all I tried it in the onePlus6Pro, so there, I debug the code and saw that all other devices were not executed, but 1) I didn't saw the SKIP at the output 2)both cases the tests started and stopped but not skipped.
the TestNG version I used is 7.4.0, and only one 'IAnnotationTransformer' listener also the annotations are from TestNG only.
the 4th point I didn't understand, I added the listener at the xml, but obviously there is class like I wrote.

Comment: This listener doesn't set Skip status, it just disables these test methods. So they aren't present in test reports at all. And not invoked too. 4) is OK, this is correct from your answer.

Comment: Also, @Before/@After methods can be executed(if exist) for the class, even if all its methods were marked as disabled by the listener.

Comment: I see, so now just need to know why it is not effect the onePlus tests, at all

Answer (score 1):

`IAnnotationTransformer` is used to modify the `@Test` annotation. And there is no option to skip a method using the `@Test` annotation. In order to forcefully skip it, you need to throw a `SkipException`.

From the code, it seems that you need to skip the test based on the class name alone and method names are not relevant. So I would suggest the use of `ITestListener` by overriding the `onTestStart` method as below:

```java
public class MyTestListener implements ITestListener {
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        String className = result.getTestClass().getName();
        if(className.contains("abc") || className.contains("xyz")) {
            throw new SkipException("Skipping class: " + className);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do this at the method level, you could use `IInvokedMethodListener`:

```java
public class MyListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
        Map<String, String> paramMap = method.getTestMethod()
                                             .findMethodParameters(result.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest());
        String className = method.getTestMethod().getTestClass().getName();
        if(className.contains(paramMap.get("deviceName"))) {
            throw new SkipException("Skipping class: " + className);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hoo sounds right, that code can get an parameter from the maven to testNG and to work according to the @Parameter ?

Comment: @nuzooo Yes you can. To get the parameters passed to the method, you could use `result.getParameters()`. To get all the parameters specified in the suite file, you could use `result.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters()`. To pass from maven, you might have to use the sure fire plugin

Comment: Yes I already use the sureFire plugin and to there I want to point exactly, to take the params from there, to pass them to the listener(code) and than to excute the code according to that

Comment: @nuzooo I think you could do that using the code i have added in my previous comment

Comment: OK Thank you, I will try that and update here when I will have results

Comment: So I got an error instead of skip in device that is not connected `Original error: Device 7efac563 was not in the list of connected devices`
 and in my onTestStart I wrote: 
`String deviceName = result.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("deviceName");
if(!deviceName.contains("S8")) {
   throw new SkipException("Skipping class: " + className);
  }`
Why it's not skipped actually?

Comment: What does `7efac563` indicate? Hope it is not the value for the incoming parameter. Also ensure that the string case is matching. If the device name is `s8` instead of `S8` then your current code won't work.

Comment: the `7efac563` is the udid of device that is not connected currently and we need to find solution to show that it will be skipped if it's not connected, it's one of the build in parameters from the TESTNG int the test of that device. the string matches the S8  since I wrote it :)

Comment: maybe there's need to find something that will not start the check if the parameter in the test already, but to test before the test is running in order not to run the test ?

Comment: @nuzooo Please debug and check if the condition is matching.

Comment: yes, the condition is OK, but it doesn't skip on it, it just say it was failed

Comment: @nuzooo are you saying that the exception is being thrown and still the test is marked as failed?

Comment: yes, exactly. it's not skipped it is failed
it's look like that : https://ufile.io/jp7ny966
now I stopped the running but it's look like what you see

Comment: I think that the problem is that at the time I already at the Listener, the test already start, and that is why it is not skipped as it should be, maybe I need something before the test?

Comment: @nuzooo this method is invoked once before each test start. I have updated the answer on skipping at the method level. try that as well

Comment: looks like that it's not working again like the picture was uploaded here, you want maybe to see it live? I still thinking that the best solution is the first one (before each test) but looks like that it fall because of the parameters that it's not getting (since the device is not connected)

Comment: can you look maybe at my code?
Maybe you will something new?

Comment: I saw that in parallel execution of two devices, I manage to do the skip at the OnStart method, but in more than two devices it doesn't succeed, also it is not show me there in context, the package name of the test actually...you have an idea?

Comment: @nuzooo `onStart` will be executed only once per `<test>` tag. I am not familiar with running via devices. But we may edit your question with your suite file. Does each device execute the suite file individually?

Comment: no, all of the test is under the same suite but different tests for each device, and it's ok that it is each per <test> tag I now just can't see that it was skipped and not see the names of the classes. I edited the question